# Customize Jenkins Job health indicator

Tags: jenkins, monitoring

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to monitor health of multiple jenkins jobs, so external monitoring tools can gather the data and set alerts.
I know about core solution that shows healthReport score based on the newest 5 builds, but
I want to customize it and set the range of checked builds for each job separately.